# Fallback strategy while migrating from one RDBMS Database to another RDBMS Database

Tags: database, database-migration, rdbms, fallback

I need to migrate application from one RDBMS database provider to another provider due to org mandate. Schema and data will be migrated too and (almost) identical. It's internal web application with backend webserver in Java+Hibernate. Challenge is how to provide fallback plan with minimum downtime in case of failure. One option is to keep original DB in sync but since app is designed to only update one (new) DB how to keep other (original) DB in sync.

P.S. This parallel run is required for a very short duration (1 week) till we are confident new setup is working. Would like to spend minimal effort for additional development as it will be throwaway.